# .NET Standard 2.0 - SqlDateTime could not be found

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard, .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .NET Standard class library project that I just updated to .NET standard 2.0 and I've updated the NuGet packages that I'm using.

But the problem is that now my project doesn't compile and failing on a few things, one of them is `The type or namespace name 'SqlDateTime' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

It was working fine before the update. So there is no SqlDateTime anymore?

Comment: There is SqlDateTime struct in System.Data.SqlTypes namespace in .NET Standard 2.0. did you try to write it with full name?